# Why shortcuts don't work in rubymine IDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine

No quick button does not work. The reason? Already search the entire Internet and found nothing. I was told that perhaps the problem in Ubuntu. We all know it works, but I have not. Who knows what?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, but my English is bad. In my Redmine IDE don`t work all shortcuts and I don`t understand why. Can you help me?

Comment: You could try assigning different shortcuts if default ones do not work ...

Comment: For example, I add the "Ctrl + C" or "Ctrl + X", and is denoted as "Ctrl + Unknown keyCode: 0x0

Comment: Better post it on their [forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/ruby?view=discussions) or [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY).

Comment: These tickets sounds similar: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111274 AND http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80613

Comment: Thank you, LazyOne! Read http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97471, found that it was necessary to put the Russian keyboard layout above the English. All works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the Russian keyboard layout above the English. Thanks [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)

Comment: I had Russian keyboard layout above the English. I put it below the English and it helped me

Answer (score 2):

Only this helped me to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to work on Russian and English keyboard in RubyMine 7:

1. Download [LinuxJavaFixes](https://github.com/zheludkovm/LinuxJavaFixes) and put the contents of `build` folder to `~/LinuxJavaFixes/build`
2. Add the following code to the RubyMine config file `..RubyMine-7.0.4/bin/rubymine64.vmoptions` *(for linux x64)*, or `..RubyMine-7.0.4/bin/rubymine.vmoptions` *(for linux x86)*:

   `-javaagent:/home/YOUR_USERNAME/LinuxJavaFixes/build/LinuxJavaFixes-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

   Change YOUR_USERNAME to your system username.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer help work with shortcut in any languages: Russian && English. Before Ctrl + C work only English keyboard. Now with both!

Answer (score 2):

This code helped me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
restart unity-settings-daemon
```

Comment: Indeed unity-settings-daemon from this package https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/ubuntu/java-non-latin-shortcuts fixed the problem for me.
Hotkeys didn't work in PHPStorm on Ubuntu 16.04 when on Russian layout and after updating from this package the problem was solved.